# C# asynchronous serial Communication

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

I'm reading data from a serial device. The software should do something I call realtime monitoring. The device a ECU from a car.

On my GUI I want to start the monitoring. To get the data, a array of 3 bytes needs to be send to the ECU. After that the ECU replies with a data package. This array should be parsed and given back to the main thread for further processing. And then a new request should be sent to the ECU, data received, parsed send back to main thread and so on. Over and over again till I stop the thread.

What will be the best way to do this? With `async` and `await`, `Backgroundworker`, `Task` or `TaskFactory`? Which will work best with the .NET serial port class?

Comment: All listed methods will work in the same way *with the .NET serial port class*. The difference is about which one looks better to *you*.

Comment: I don't believe the .NET SerialPort class supports async/await.

Comment: @ErikPhilips It does not, but you can call your synchronous method with `Task.Run`.

Comment: No matter how you slice it, then it will use a Thread, instead of a Completion Port.

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet how you would start a async serial read that wont block the main thread?

Answer (score -1):

When calling the sync call inside an async request you are ok to ignore threading and callbacks as the Task class with his state Maschine will make a new thread for you, feel free to do blocking calls inside the "await"

Comment: `state Maschine will make a new thread for you` -  [no it won't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx), unless specifically asked.